# Determine library path programmatically in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm new to makefile, and I'm writing a simple C++ shared library.

Is there a way of finding a library's path dynamically by the makefile itself? What I want is something like this: (in my makefile)

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := `which amplex-gui`
LIBRARY_DIRS := `which amplex-gui`
```

amplex-gui is a library I use in my code, and I need to put its lib and include directories in my makefile. I want to figure out its path dynamically because each user might install it in a different path on their machine. Therefore, I need my makefile to dynamically parse the which command (or perhaps the $PATH environment variable) to find that path. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You can certainly write a program or script whose output is turned into a macro. However `which amplex-gui` will only work if `amplex-gui` is an executable file, not if it's a name of a library or similar. To solve that, you'll need some other mechanism - for example a list of "likely" candidates, and if that fails, use `find`, perhaps?

Comment: Remember that backquotes is shell syntax.  Make doesn't do anything special with backquotes.  If you're using GNU make, you can use `$(shell which amplex-gui)` to get equivalent behavior as backquotes.

Comment: thanks @MadScientist, this worked great. Also, I discovered I cannot nest commands using the `$()` way. I wanted to get the second parent (2 levels up) of the result of the `which` command, but I had to create three different variables. If you put your comment into an answer I would accept it.

Comment: What you are doing could be done by a config program.  When you install, the config program finds amplex-gui and puts the path in your makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that backquoting is shell syntax. Make doesn't do anything special with backquotes. If you're using GNU make, you can use $(shell which amplex-gui) to get equivalent behavior as backquotes.

Regarding your comment above, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "nest commands", but you can definitely use the shell's `$()` syntax within a make `shell` function.  However, as with *all* strings that make expands, you need to double the dollar signs to quote them so that they are passed to the shell.  So for example:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(shell echo $$(dirname $$(dirname $$(which amplex-gui))))
```

Of course you can also use make functions; unfortunately the make `dir` function is annoying in that it leaves the final slash, so it cannot be used multiple times directly.  You have to put a patsubst in there, like:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(dir $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(shell which amplex-gui))))
```

Finally, if you have a sufficiently new version of GNU make there's the `abspath` function, so you could do something like this:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(abspath $(dir $(shell which amplex-gui))../..)
```